# How to show volume indicator when change system volume in code

Tags: macos, cocoa

In my mac application, I change the system volume in code. I want the system volume indicator to appear that gives visual clue of how loud the sound is now.

[image]

I have searched through the Internet, but no lucky on me. And I can't detect this indicator using Accessibility Inspector.